# LaTeX a4 trifold flyer

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I get, from LaTeX, this a4 flyer?
I would like to achieve the background colors with TikZ PGF package. Could you help me? 
Thank you!

[image: colors, tables, pictures]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please post what you've got so far?

Comment: I would like to achieve the background colors with TikZ PGF package.  Could you help me?

Comment: Your changed question looks like a "Do this complicate thing for me" question. Note, your chance for an answer would be much better, if you'd show us, what you already have and ask a concrete question where you failed. Questions like yours are often closed as too broad or unclear. This is why I cannot vote to reopen it currently.